# Magento Category Title above sidebar and main content

Tags: category, page-title

```
I am using Magento version 1.9.2.0
```

I am trying to split up the 2-columns-left template on the category pages.

### Right now

it looks like this:

[image: right now]

---

### I need

the category name and description to move up over the left menu, and fill the width 100% like this:

[image]

I cant figure out where to start. When I look in the XML it seems to not be a separate part that I can place elsewhere.

Result need to be:

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy to handle because category title is part of the main content itself.

I had a similar problem and I solved with a jQuery trick by moving the title outside the main content. I know it is not the more elegant way, but it is the fastest and it is quite simple.

Something like this:

```
jQuery("div.page-title").detach().prependTo('div.col-main');
```